# promise.all executes the promises in a parallel manner but how the single threads JS works in background

Tags: javascript, promise

promise.all executes the promises in a parallel manner but how exactly the single threaded JS handles it and process it in background .

Comment: Promises aren't "executed"; they represent an already-running async task.

Comment: Read https://blog.slaks.net/2014-12-23/parallelism-async-threading-explained/

Comment: Check out https://jsblog.insiderattack.net/promises-next-ticks-and-immediates-nodejs-event-loop-part-3-9226cbe7a6aa

Comment: thanks @SLaks  for the info

Comment: Take the time to watch this talk about the JS event loop. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ